# How do I traverse binary tree made up of nodes? (code inside)

Tags: python, class, binary-tree, nodes

I am given a class that creates a binary tree filled with nodes.each node is given a parent and a pointer to its left or right child.

Binary tree node class:

```
class BTNode():
''' a class that represents a binary tree node'''
def __init__(self, data, parent=None, left_child=None, right_child=None):
    '''(BTNode, obj, BTNode, BTNode, BTNode) -> NoneType
    Constructs a binary tree nodes with the given data'''

    self._parent = parent
    self._left = left_child
    self._data = data
    self._right = right_child

def set_parent(self, parent):
    '''(BTNode, BTNode) -> NoneType
    set the parent to the given node'''
    self._parent = parent
def set_left(self, left_child):
    '''(BTNode, BTNode) -> NoneType
    set the left child to the given node'''
    self._left = left_child

def set_right(self, right_child):
    '''(BTNode, BTNode) -> NoneType
    set the right child to the given node'''
    self._right = right_child
def set_data(self, data):
    '''(BTNode, obj) -> NoneType
    set the data at this node to the given data'''
    self._data = data    

def get_parent(self):
    '''(BTNode) -> BTNode
    return the pointer to the parent of this node'''
    return self._parent

def get_left(self):
    '''(BTNode) -> BTNode
    return the pointer to the left child'''
    return self._left

def get_right(self):
    '''(BTNode) -> BTNode
    return the pointer to the right child'''
    return self._right   
def get_data(self):
    '''(BTNode) -> obj
    return the data stored in this node'''
    return self._data

def has_left(self):
    '''(BTNode) -> bool
    returns true if this node has a left child'''
    return (self.get_left() is not None)
def has_right(self):
    '''(BTNode) -> bool
    returns true if this node has a right child'''
    return (self.get_right() is not None)  
def is_left(self):
    '''(BTNode) -> bool
    returns true if this node is a left child of its parent'''
    # you need to take care of exception here, if the given node has not parent
    return (self.get_parent().get_left() is self)
def is_right(self):
    '''(BTNode) -> bool
    returns true if the given node is a right child of its parent'''
    # you need to take care of exception here, if the given node has not parent
    return (self.get_parent().get_right() is self)
def is_root(self):
    '''(BTNode) -> bool
    returns true if the given node has not parent i.e. a root '''
    return (self.get_parent() is None)
```

code example of how to create a tree:

```
''' create this BT using BTNode
             A
           /   \
         B      C   
        /\       \
       D  E      F
                /
               G
'''
node_G = BTNode("G")
node_F = BTNode("F", None,node_G)
node_G.set_parent(node_F)
node_C = BTNode("C", None, None, node_F)
node_F.set_parent(node_C)
node_D = BTNode("D")
node_E = BTNode("E")
node_B = BTNode("B",None, node_D, node_E)
node_D.set_parent(node_B)
node_E.set_parent(node_B)
node_A = BTNode("A",None, node_B, node_C)
node_B.set_parent(node_A)
```

I dont know how to traverse this tree. I was suggested using recursion but Im not sure how. For example, I need to return True if the tree differs in height by at most 1 level,so the tree above would return true. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "differs in height by at most 1 level"?

Comment: I mean for every node in the tree, its left and right subtrees only differ by at most 1 level. So for the root node A,its left and right trees differ by one as an example. For B they are equal which is also fine. If any nodes subtrees differ by more than one return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to think recursively. Let's start off with a few definitions.

- A tree is balanced if its left and right trees have the same height and each of it's subtrees is balanced. Also we will define an empty tree as being balanced.
- The height of a tree, h(t) = 1 + max(h(t.left), h(t.right)). In English, the height of a tree is 1 + the height of its taller child tree. Also we will assume that an empty tree has a height of 0.

So for every node in the tree we can check the height of both of its children and compare them. If they aren't equal we know the tree is not balanced and we return false.

Let's start by defining the code to check if a tree is balanced.

```
def is_balanced(node):
    if node is None:
        return True
    left_height = get_height(node.get_left())
    right_height = get_height(node.get_right())
    return left_height == right_height and is_balanced(node.get_left()) and is_balanced(node.get_right())
```

Now let's define the function `get_height` that we used above. Since the height of a tree is a function of a height of it's subtrees we can use recursion. Since recursion requires a base case so we do not recurse infinitely we can use the fact that an empty tree has a height of 0.

```
def get_height(node):
    if node is None:
        return 0 # Assuming empty tree has a height of 0
    return 1 + max(get_height(node.get_left()), get_height(node.get_right()))
```

Now to put it all together we can recursively iterate through the tree and check that every node is balanced by calling `is_balanced` on the root.

`is_balanced(node_A)`

BONUS Exercise:
The code I gave you will work but it won't scale well. If the tree gets very large it will run much slower. Why is it slow and what can you do to make it faster?

Comment: I will try this code and the excercise later tonight when I can and send my answer then, thank you for the write up! Another question I thought of is how would you count the number of nodes in the tree? Would this recursion method work as well?

Comment: Yea recursion is the way to go. When you think of a tree it is inherently recursive right? A tree is a node with 0-2 subtrees. Any time you want to iterate through each node in a tree you want to use recursion.

Answer (score -1):

You can traverse the left and right sides of the tree to find the maximum path length to a leaf:

```
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__ = {i:kwargs.get(i) for i in ['value', 'left', 'right']}
  def get_length(self, current=[]):
    yield current+[1]
    yield from getattr(self.left, 'get_length', lambda _:[])(current+[1])
    yield from getattr(self.right, 'get_length', lambda _:[])(current+[1])
  def right_length(self):
    return len(max(getattr(self.right, 'get_length', lambda :[[]])(), key=len))
  def left_length(self):
    return len(max(getattr(self.left, 'get_length', lambda :[[]])(), key=len))

t = Tree(value = 'A', left=Tree(value='B', left=Tree(value='D'), right=Tree(value='E')), right = Tree(value='C', left = Tree(value='F', left=Tree(value='G'))))
print(t.right_length() - t.left_length())
```

Output:

```
1
```